# Can I use name of the color as alt text for the image?

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag2.0

We testing our website for WCAG 2.0 Level A combability. We have yarns in different color shades hence the alt text would contain the name of the shade. But while testing we got an error.

[image: error 1 - a warning on the use of "gray", but this error is erroneous]

[image: error 2 - error for an image without an alt description]

Are we allowed to use the shade color name?

Comment: Out of context it is hard to say whether your markup is correct, but you can use shades and colours to describe an object. The warnings are designed to stop people doing "please click the red button" type instructions. The first example I am 99% sure is fine but the second one doesn't actually show the `alt` - I am guessing the text after the `[...]` is `alt` text in which case it is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image alt attribute best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613173/image-alt-attribute-best-practices)